# Problem with associating accounts in new private beta

Tags: support, global-inbox

I just joined the history private beta and since this was my first time on today I noticed I had a notification for 1 item.

When I clicked on Inbox in the super-collider the Inbox section was blank. I assumed there wouldn't be a problem because when I signed in with SSO it suggested to link my accounts.

When checking my accounts page it has a message I've never seen before:

"These associations are changing, please check back in 14 minutes."

I'm *guessing* the problem with my missing Inbox will resolve in 14 minutes?

I couldn't find the meaning of this message mentioned on meta. If this is not the reason, can someone please explain the message for future reference anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aye, looks like this was just a temporary glitch.  Seems like [your inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/47040?tab=inbox) is properly filled now?

As to the message, these actions are done in a queue at the network level, and as such may not be done immediately.